# Why do Exception and println() lines come out in different order each time for the same program?

Tags: java, exception, jvm, println

I noticed something strange while working on a small project of mine: I laced the code with some `System.out.println();` lines to track down a bug. Curiously enough, when I run the buggy program from the IDE, the lines of the Exception stacktrace and the printout of some of those print statements come out in different order each time the program is ran. Common sense would dictate that the same program runs the same way each time, exceptions included, so the output must also be the same for all executions. However, this is not the case. The content of the lines remain the same, and the order of both the stacktrace lines and the printout lines remains consistent, but they are intermixed differently each time. So on one run, the console output is

```
populatePinArrays: An input pin added to gate!
populatePinArrays: An input pin added to gate!
populatePinArrays: An output pin added to gate!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Gates.Pin.isReadyToEvaluate(Pin.java:28)
    at Gates.Pin.evaluate(Pin.java:19)
    at Gates.TheCircuit.evaluateTheCircuit(TheCircuit.java:42)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
CircEval: all set to dirty
CircEval: all input pins set to clean
```

while the next time it can be

```
Exception in thread "main" populatePinArrays: An input pin added to gate!
populatePinArrays: An input pin added to gate!
java.lang.NullPointerException
populatePinArrays: An output pin added to gate!
CircEval: all set to dirty
CircEval: all input pins set to clean
    at Gates.Pin.isReadyToEvaluate(Pin.java:28)
    at Gates.Pin.evaluate(Pin.java:19)
    at Gates.TheCircuit.evaluateTheCircuit(TheCircuit.java:42)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I'm mainly asking out of curiosity about what Java/JVM nitty gritty is responsible and what exactly is happening under the hood, but if this thing occurring points to some flaw in my program, I would like to know.

Comment: Don't you think the code might be relevant to your question?

Comment: "Common sense would dictate that the same program runs the same way each time, exceptions included". Common sense maybe, but programmer sense definitely knows that's not true.

Comment: Common sense would dictate that two different streams can be flushed at different times. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exception stacktraces are written to `stderr` whereas your normal output is written to `stdout`. They both end up in the same place (in this case, not always), but since they're not the same stream it's possible for them to interleave in wildly different ways.

If you were to convert your `System.out.println`s to `System.err.println`s (or print the stacktrace to stdout with `e.printStackTrace(System.out);`) you'd see this doesn't happen anymore.